# How should I fix this error involving PHP function static?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, static

Any help would be very welcome! I have site that's been down for weeks because of a single parse error and I can't figure it out.

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/chymel/public_html/signaladvance/wp-content/themes/OLD_Divi/includes/builder/core.php on line 5662

Below, a screenshot of line 5661 - 5671 which is simply:

```php
function et_builder_maybe_wrap_css_selector($selector, $suffix = '', $clone = true) {
  static $should_wrap_selectors = ;
  $post_id = ET_Builder_Element::get_theme_builder_layout_id();
  if ( ! isset( $should_wrap_selectors[ $post_id ] ) ) {
     $should_wrap_selectors[ $post_id ] = et_is_builder_plugin_active() ||
      et_builder_is_custom_post_type_archive() ||
      ( et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( $post_id ) &&
        (et_builder_post_is_of_custom_post_type( $post_id ) ||
        et_theme_builder_is_layout_post_type( get_post_type( $post_id ) )
      ));
```

What is causing the site to not show up at all? Instead, I get a parse error ?...

Comment: In `static $should_wrap_selectors = ;` the assignment is missing. Could you show us more code of this file?

Comment: Sure thank you and my apologies!  
*/
function et_builder_maybe_wrap_css_selector( $selector, $suffix = '', $clone = true ) {
 static $should_wrap_selectors = ;

 $post_id = ET_Builder_Element::get_theme_builder_layout_id();

 if ( ! isset( $should_wrap_selectors[ $post_id ] ) ) {
  $should_wrap_selectors[ $post_id ] = et_is_builder_plugin_active() || et_builder_is_custom_post_type_archive() || ( et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( $post_id ) && ( et_builder_post_is_of_custom_post_type( $post_id ) || et_theme_builder_is_layout_post_type( get_post_type( $post_id ) ) ) );

Comment: Either put a value for `$should_wrap_selectors` or remove the ` = ` part if you're not going to put value there.

Comment: Thank you! So you're saying it would become                                                  function et_builder_maybe_wrap_css_selector( $selector, $suffix = '', $clone = true ) {
 static $should_wrap_selectors